# How can I call python module inside versioned package folder?

Tags: python

I need write python codes which run inside a host application. The python codes should be deployed under a specific folder of the host application. I must put my entry python module under the root of the specific folder. And I want put all my other python codes and c/c++ dll under a sub folder, I prefer to name the sub folder like XXX-1.0, the number is the version of my python codes. The entry python module is just simple call a python module under the sub-folder.

By this way different version python codes can be deployed together without collision. May I know it is possible or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your question correctly, but here is a simple way to have several package versions without collisions.

A directory structure:

```
C:\tmp\eggs>dir /B /S
C:\tmp\eggs\libs
C:\tmp\eggs\test.py
C:\tmp\eggs\libs\foo-1.0.egg
C:\tmp\eggs\libs\foo-2.0.egg
C:\tmp\eggs\libs\foo-1.0.egg\foo.py
C:\tmp\eggs\libs\foo-2.0.egg\foo.py
```

Now the contents of files:

```
# contents of C:\tmp\eggs\libs\foo-1.0.egg\foo.py
version=(1,0)
```

---

```
# contents of C:\tmp\eggs\libs\foo-2.0.egg\foo.py
version=(2,0)
```

---

```
#contents of C:\tmp\eggs\test.py:

import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'libs')
from pkg_resources import require

require('foo<1.5')
import foo
print foo.version
# will output (1,0)
```

If you change `'foo<1.5'` to `'foo>1.5'`, or `'foo'` output will change to `(2,0)`

Details you will find in [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs#automatic-discovery) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you created a `.pth` file, eg., `X.pth` and put `XXX-1.0` inside as content

```
XXX-1.0\
        - xxx.py
X.pth
```

Then, you could `import xxx`

**Note**: only tested on site-packages folder, I am not sure you could put your sub folder anywhere.

**Edit**:
For example, wxPython do that way, since it can have multiple version on same machine.

```
wx-2.8-msw-unicode \
                    wx
                      \
                       more stuff
wx.pth (wx-2.8-msw-unicode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done it:

```
tools
  |-- packageA
        |-- packageA-1.0
              |-- packageA
                    |-- modules
        |-- packageA-2.0
              |-- packageA
                    |-- modules
  |-- packageB
        ...
```

This way, when you want to upgrade, just add /packageA/packageA-2.0 to the PYTHONPATH and you can still do `import packageA`.